# About butterworth filter

Tags: c#, filtering

I'm trying to use the Butterworth filter described [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1092012/A-Butterworth-Filter-in-Csharp). I have a few small questions.

- how to choose the deltatime if my input values are not "temporaly" separated ? In my case, the data I want to run through the filter are the distance-to-black of a serie of pixels.
- I used the code as it is presented in the above link. The output data are stored in the `data`double array. When I try to plot the filtered data (see code hereafter), the calls for `data.Count` and `data[i]` are not working : `the name "data" does not exist in this context`(or something similar, I run a french version of VS). I can't for the hell of me figure out why, but I'm sure it's painfully obvious... Here is the code :

  ```
  { 
      //BUTTERWORTH CODE
  }

  public void smoothDataButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      for (int i = 1 ; i < data.Count; i++)
      chart1.Series["Smoothed experiment"].Points.AddXY(i, data[i]);
  }
  ```

I hope my explanation is clear !

Thanks a lot, and have a nice day.

Comment: The smoothDatatButton_Click function doesn't have local variable 'data' neither method parameter, but you reference it. You should make 'data' variable in containing class or invoke Butterworth code inside your click handler like var data = Butterworth(...);

Comment: Where do you create the `data` variable?

Comment: Deltatime is in nsec and should be at least 2N (Nystrom) where N is the Max frequency. So if you max frequency is 100MHz  your sample rate should be > 200MHz.  So 1/200MHz = 5nsec (or less).

Comment: @jdweng, I see you didn't read the question.  The frequency is in cycles per inch, not MHz.  So the sampling interval will not be in nanoseconds.